# Equality Range Query in MySQL runs very slowly

Tags: mysql, query-performance

`Table event (id, source_id, start_time), 140k records`
`Index (source_id asc, start_time desc)`

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM event where source_id in (4, 5, 3, 10)
order by start_time desc limit 100;
```

Run time ~ 2 seconds.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | event | null | ALL | idx_source_start_time | null | null | null | 125504 | 100 | Using where; Using filesort |

Currently, my table only has event of source_id 3, no event of source 4, 5, 10. With index (camera_id, start_time), I think that MySQL will dive into BTree and know source 4, 5, 10 have no matched records. But this query runs very slow. How can I optimize this query ?

Comment: *I think that MySQL will dive into BTree and know source 4, 5, 10 have no matched records.* No. MySQL can detect this only during the query execution, so this cannot be taken into account during the execution plan building.

Comment: *How can I optimize this query ?* Select using `where source_id = X`, 100 rows per value (Index should work), then UNION ALL and one more ORDER BY + LIMIT.

Comment: @Akina Using union, run time is 120ms. However, my query can have up to 50 sources. I think MySQL must do this UNION internally for query IN (...).

Comment: *I think MySQL must* MySQL does not make any assumptions. It uses only available facts. For example, the fact about the data (your words about "source 4, 5, 10 have no matched records") which can be taken from the table statistic is approximate, so it won't be taken into consideration.

Comment: @Akina I mean, with index (source, start_time), MySQL can fast retrieve records of each sources and statistics data. And it only should get 100 results of each sources then run union + sort. This query should be faster. Writing SQL with 50 union is complex (and ugly).

Comment: `IN` is not "equality".

Comment: As the `EXPLAIN` says, the query will do a full table scan, then sort all the rows from those 4 source_ids, and finally deliver 100.  The "sort" will be fast if very few rows exist after the filtering; or very slow if there are lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MSQL version is at least 8.0.14 you can use VALUES to construct a list of `sources_id`, then use a LATERAL join to force the extraction of 100 events for each `source_id` and then order by `start_time` to get the latest 100 overall.

```
SELECT filtered_events.* FROM 
  (VALUES ROW(4),ROW(5),ROW(3),ROW(10)) AS sources(id)
JOIN LATERAL 
  (SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.source_id = sources.id 
   ORDER BY source_id asc, start_time desc LIMIT 100) AS filtered_events 
ORDER BY start_time desc LIMIT 100;
```

The filtered_events subquery should then use your `Index (source_id asc, start_time desc)`

Comment: This query works fine. But I have to use raw query rather than using ORM. Thanks !

Comment: @shang12 - ORMs are not designed for performance.

Comment: In a similar test, this showed that my `UNION` approach may be faster than `LATERAL`:  `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`

Answer (score 0):

I would put in an index  on `start_time, source_id`.  Since you are ordering by `start_time` and filtering by `source_id`.

Comment: This will cause index scan (not index seek), and anycase this should use final filesort.

Comment: @Akina Using this index (start_time, source_id), query time is 100 ms. It will scan index, and not efficient if events of a filtered source only have at the end of BTree (not test).
However, with current event data, it works fine.

Comment: I have just tested again. Index (start_time, source_id) only efficient for filtering list of sources which contain source_id 3. The other queries run slowly.

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT * FROM event WHERE source_id = 4  ORDER BY start_time DESC  LIMIT 100 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM event WHERE source_id = 5  ORDER BY start_time DESC  LIMIT 100 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM event WHERE source_id = 3  ORDER BY start_time DESC  LIMIT 100 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM event WHERE source_id = 10 ORDER BY start_time DESC  LIMIT 100 )
)  ORDER BY start_time DESC  LIMIT 100;
```

Yes, it depends on `INDEX (source_id, start_time)`, but note that `ASC` and `DESC` don't matter in the index.  Each `SELECT` will optimally use the index; the final `ORDER BY` will need to sort only 4*100 rows.

(This works if you don't have a version with `LATERAL`.)

If you need to paginate, let me know; it gets a bit tricky.

Performance will depend on data distribution, the LIMIT value, the number of source_ids selected, and the phase of the moon.

Comment: Your query works, but if there are 50 source ids, this query looks a bit long and ugly. However, I can use ORM for writing this union query.