# Create indexes for pagination API

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table `event (id, user_id, category_id, source_id, start_time, is_read) with 8M records`. I need to list events with paging for 6 types of APIs below (each API needs 2 DB queries)

**API 1**

```
Count number of events:
SELECT count(id) from event
WHERE user_id=1;

Get a page:
SELECT * from event
WHERE user_id=1
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

**API 2**

```
Count:
SELECT * from event
WHERE user_id=1 AND is_read=0;

Get a page:
SELECT * from event
WHERE user_id=1 AND is_read=0
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

**API 3**

```
.........
WHERE user_id=1 AND category_id in (1, 3, 5)
```

**API 4**

```
.........
WHERE user_id=1 AND category_id in (1, 3, 5) AND is_read=0
```

**API 5**

```
.........
WHERE user_id=1 AND category_id = 1 AND source_id in (10, 12, 13)
```

**API 6**

```
.........
WHERE user_id=1 AND category_id = 1 AND source_id in (10, 12, 13) AND is_read=0
```

This is my indexes:

```
API 1: (user_id, start_time)
API 2: (user_id, is_read, start_time)
API 3: (user_id, category_id, start_time)
API 4: (user_id, category_id, is_read, start_time)
API 5: (user_id, category_id, source_id, start_time)
API 6: (user_id, category_id, source_id, is_read, start_time)
```

- List of categories have up to 100 ids
- is_read = 0 or 1

Table `event` has 3 more indexes (id, foreign key). I'm worried about using many indexes in a table.
Can anyone help me review my table design ?

Answer (score 3):

**Improvements on your indexes**

```
API 4: (user_id, is_read, category_id, start_time)
API 6: (user_id, is_read, category_id, source_id, start_time)
```

**Simplified rules for making optimal indexes**

1. Put columns tested with '='
2. `IN`
3. range or `ORDER BY`.

The cardinality does *not* matter.

More:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

**Even better**

"Cluster" the `PRIMARY KEY` starting with `user_id`.  Assuming you have `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`, I would change to this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, is_read, id),  -- for clustering most of your queries
INDEX(id),    -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
INDEX(user_id, start_time),
INDEX(user_id, category_id, start_time),
INDEX(user_id, source_id, category_id, start_time)
```

Then have the only indexes 1,3,5.  With that PK, there is very little benefit to having indexes 2,4,6.  I modified #5 in case there are also queries that might need to look at source_id.

Note that `source_id IN (11)` (a single item) is optimized like `source_id = 11`.

**Pagination**

This may help:  [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Comment: Thank you very much ! If removing indexes with is_read (2, 4, 6), counting is very slow. SELECT count(id) FROM event WHERE user_id = 1 AND is_read = 0, run time is 8 seconds. With index (user_id, is_read, start_time) => 500ms.

Comment: With query category_in IN [...], I have to use JOIN LATERAL. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/324822/270684

Comment: @shang12 - How would you use `LATERAL` in this case?

Comment: For that slow query, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Hi, if follow your rule, index for query "user_id=1 AND category_id = 1 AND source_id in (10, 12, 13)", should be (user_id, category_id, source_id).  I also don't find any clear rules for "IN operator" in Index Cookbook (It says "IN (1,99,3) is sometimes optimized as efficiently as "=", but not always")

Comment: @shang12 - I agree with that 3-col index.

Comment: @shang12 - (re IN)    In many applications, the `IN` clause _sometimes_ has only one item.  In that case, the Optimizer _does_ turn that into `=` and may pick a different index.  In some cases, it will hop through the table.  In other cases, the `IN` can't be optimized.  So, no, I don't have any "clear rules".  Sorry.