# Optimizie MySQL query: col_name IN (val1, ..., valN)

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

I had posted a question about mysql equality range optimization [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/324816/equality-range-query-in-mysql-runs-very-slowly).
At this post, I want to discuss about why mysql optimizer is too bad for this type of query: `col_name IN (val1, ..., valN)`.

```sql
My table:
alert_user(id, user_id, source_id, start_time, is_read, ...)

Indexes:
idx_user_start(user_id, start_time)
idx_user_read_start(user_id, is_read, start_time)
idx_user_source_start(user_id, source_id, start_time)
idx_user_read_source_start(user_id, is_read, source_id, start_time)

Records: 30M
Records of user_id 1: 6M
```

**1. Query 1**

```sql
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user
WHERE user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 48)
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Run: 170s

- access_type: index
- key: idx_user_start
- key_length: 12

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "1316696.93"
        },
        "ordering_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "alert_user",
                "access_type": "index",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "idx_user_source_start",
                    "idx_user_start",
                    "idx_user_read_start",
                    "idx_user_read_source_start"
                ],
                "key": "idx_user_start",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "user_id",
                    "start_time"
                ],
                "key_length": "12",
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 314,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 2540666,
                "filtered": "4.57",
                "backward_index_scan": true,
                "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "46363.53",
                    "eval_cost": "254066.68",
                    "prefix_cost": "1316696.93",
                    "data_read_per_join": "193M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "user_id",
                    "is_read",
                    "start_time",
                    "source_id"
                ],
                "attached_condition": "((`test2`.`alert_user`.`user_id` = 1) and (`test2`.`alert_user`.`source_id` in (3,48)))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Query 2**

```json
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user use index (idx_user_source_start)
WHERE (user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 48))
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Run: 3s

- access_type: range
- key: idx_user_source_start
- key_length: 12

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "2142293.68"
        },
        "ordering_operation": {
            "using_filesort": true,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "alert_user",
                "access_type": "range",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "idx_user_source_start"
                ],
                "key": "idx_user_source_start",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "user_id",
                    "source_id"
                ],
                "key_length": "12",
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 1826304,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 1826304,
                "filtered": "100.00",
                "index_condition": "((`test2`.`alert_user`.`user_id` = 1) and (`test2`.`alert_user`.`source_id` in (3,48)))",
                "using_MRR": true,
                "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "1959663.28",
                    "eval_cost": "182630.40",
                    "prefix_cost": "2142293.68",
                    "data_read_per_join": "139M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "user_id",
                    "is_read",
                    "start_time",
                    "source_id"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Query 3**
I deleted 2 indexes which contain is_read, and run query

```sql
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user
WHERE (user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 48))
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Run: < 1s

- access_type: ref
- key: idx_user_start
- key_length: 4

```json
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
            "query_cost": "1903471.80"
        },
        "ordering_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "alert_user",
                "access_type": "ref",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "idx_user_source_start",
                    "idx_user_start"
                ],
                "key": "idx_user_start",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "user_id"
                ],
                "key_length": "4",
                "ref": [
                    "const"
                ],
                "rows_examined_per_scan": 11740588,
                "rows_produced_per_join": 2348117,
                "filtered": "20.00",
                "backward_index_scan": true,
                "cost_info": {
                    "read_cost": "729413.00",
                    "eval_cost": "234811.76",
                    "prefix_cost": "1903471.80",
                    "data_read_per_join": "179M"
                },
                "used_columns": [
                    "id",
                    "user_id",
                    "is_read",
                    "start_time",
                    "source_id"
                ],
                "attached_condition": "(`test2`.`alert_user`.`source_id` in (3,48))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mysql uses 3 different execution strategies for the above 3 queries. All are slow.
I know 2 methods to optimize the above query:

- Use [UNION](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/325480/270684) (< 400ms)
- Use [Lateral JOIN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/324822/270684) (< 400ms)

However, I still have to hint mysql use index idx_user_source_start. Maybe creating many indexes makes mysql cannot choose the optimal index.

Second, I feel a bit tired because I have to rewriting SQL to UNION when query contain IN (val1, val2,...).

Have anyone faced this problem in MySQL, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This index may be faster, but still not 'perfect':

```
INDEX(user_id, source_id,    -- either order is equally good
      start_time,            -- a range
      is_read)               -- for "covering"
```

When you add that index, remove any that are a left subset of it, namely idx_user_source_start.

Once you have that index, this will be even faster (at least if the table is 'large'):

```
( SELECT  id, source_id, is_read, start_time
    FROM  alert_user
    WHERE  user_id = 1
      AND  source_id = 3 
    ORDER BY  start_time DESC
    LIMIT  100
) UNION ALL
( SELECT  id, source_id, is_read, start_time
    FROM  alert_user
    WHERE  user_id = 1
      AND  source_id = 48
    ORDER BY  start_time DESC
    LIMIT  100
)
ORDER BY start_time DESC   -- yes, again
LIMIT 100;
```

I realize that it may not be practical to break up the `IN` (or `OR`) and make `UNIONs`.  But nothing else will be efficiently executed.

Leaving off the `is_read` will be nearly as good.  In either case, it will do 200 fetches, build a temp table (probably in RAM), re-sort and trim down to 100.

If you will be using `OFFSET`, too, it gets a little trickier:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or

**Case 1 (and subcases)**

- The Optimizer usually fails to notice a `LIMIT` and factor it into picking a plan.  More specifically...
- When scanning and filtering and limiting, the 'limit' rows could be in the first few rows scanned, or they could be at the far end of the table.
- When there is a choice between picking an index that handles *part* of a `WHERE` but includes the `ORDER BY` versus handles all of the `WHERE` and not the `ORDER BY`, the Optimizer can all-to-easily make the wrong choice.
- `IN` with multiple values is usually as bad as a "range" -- columns after it in the `INDEX` are ignored.
- As you observed, a change in the data distribution and/or items in `IN` can make a big difference in performance.  Be aware that the Optimizer does not do adequate research to discover this.
- Avoiding `IN` (or, `OR`) by using `UNION` (as exemplified above) lets more columns of an index be used, even to the point of stopping short of scanning the entire table.

**The 'real' answer** of how MySQL's Optimizer works is its "cost model".  I do not attempt to follow that.  (See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and "Optimizer trace".)  I try to optimization it by saying "given this template, the Optimizer will usually want `INDEX(...)`.  But if that index is not available, here is what it will do with the existing `INDEXes`.  The cost model depends on statistics which are less than perfect.  For example, there is no "histogram" indicating that a column has an unbalanced set of values.  (MariaDB attempts to do such.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. UNION is the query I'm still using. I want to discuss about mysql execution plan. Hope you can take a moment to review my new post. Thank you very much !

Comment: @shang12 - I chose to explain the issues rather than dig into your analysis.

Comment: I understand that my post is too long. I have read your INDEX Cookbook. I just want to have a better understanding of how MySQL works, so the question is a bit long.

Comment: @shang12 - Your Question gets beyond what my cookbook covers.  And it gets into a lot of "maybes" and "sometimes".  In this case, the combination of `IN`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` makes it hart for the Optimizer to do the right thing.

Comment: @shang12 - I added more.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions. In case 2 (2.1 vs 1.1), same query, same index but mysql uses 2 different join types (ref and index), what influenced optimizer's decision ?

Comment: @shang12 - I don't know.  Guesses:  (1) the extra indexes distracted the Optimizer. (2) the statistics (via random probes) came up with different values.  Did you add rows or do anything else to change the contents of the table?

Comment: I clone the real table to the test table. There are not any modifications about data on this test table (insert, update, delete).

Comment: @shang12 - OK, It remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for your reply. I think that UNION is the most optimal query.
If you don't mind, I'd like to discuss about how MySQL chooses the execution plan.

Table `alert_user` has other columns besides the ones above. As for source_id, here are some examples:

- Source  3 contains data with start_time in [2023-04-01 -> 2023-04-17]
- Source 29 contains data with start_time in [2023-04-01 -> 2023-06-29]
- Source 48 contains data with start_time in [2023-04-01 -> 2023-07-11]

### Case 1: When table alert_user only contains 2 indexes `idx_user_start` and `idx_user_source_start`

#### Test 1.1

```
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user
WHERE (user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 29))
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;

MySQL uses idx_user_start (access_type ref), run time is 11s
```

#### Query 1.2: Hint MySQL to use index

```
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user USE INDEX (idx_user_source_start)
WHERE (user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 29))
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;

MySQL use idx_user_source_start, run time is 1.7s
```

#### Query 1.3

```
.... source_id IN (3, 48) ...
MySQL use idx_user_start, run time is 0.5s, it runs fast because source 48 has many records recently.
```

#### Query 1.4: Hint MySQL to use index

```
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user USE INDEX (idx_user_source_start)
WHERE (user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 48))
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;

MySQL use idx_user_source_start, run time is 3.2s
```

#### Query 1.5: The most optimal query

```
UNION: 0.1s
UNION with index hint (idx_user_source_start): 0.1s
```

### Case 2: When alert_user only contains 4 indexes `idx_user_start, idx_user_source_start, idx_user_read_start, idx_user_read_source_start`

#### Test 2.1

```
SELECT id, source_id, is_read, start_time
FROM alert_user
WHERE (user_id = 1 AND source_id IN (3, 29))
ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 100;
```

MySQL uses `idx_user_start` (access_type index), run time has increased to 120s, very slow when compared with query 1.1. I found that mysql plan use `access_type` is `index`, different with `access_type: ref` of query 1.1.

Can you explain to me why MySQL chose the above execution plans.

#### 1. Query 1.1 and 1.2

Why MySQL chose idx_user_start instead of idx_user_source_start

#### 2. Query 1.1 and 2.1

Why is there a difference in access_type strategy ?

#### 3. Is mysql optimizer not smart enough to

- Optimize query IN (val1,..,valN)
- When table has many indexes, mysql failed to choose the correct index. I have to use index hint in other queries
- After much time working with mysql, I came to the conclusion that
  that it's always better to use UNION and index hint. Do you have the same thoughts ?

Many thanks !

Comment: First, be sure to run each query twice.  If the data is not yet cached in the buffer pool, the query will run a lot slower.  Hence, conclusions about relative timings could be incorrect.

Comment: For each query, I ran it multiple times and took the average time.

Comment: Change the IN values to rarer or more common values.  Change the LIMIT to more or less.  Change the user_id.  The timing may change dramaticaly, but the Explain may not.  You are into hard-to-predict areas.